# REST API, OAuth2 and authentification errors

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, oauth-2.0, passport.js

First, thanks you for your replies. 
I try to make an REST API with nodeJS, and i think, oAuth2 is the best way to authenticates users against my system.

Users are stored in LDAP, and api keys will be keep on MySQL engine. Client account code will be also store in MySQL.
All process is OK, users are authenticated, API token has been saved in MySQL but when i try to use this token, passport refuse to authenticated my request and return :

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:62:20)
    at ServerResponse.res.header (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:280:8)
    at ServerResponse.res.json (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:135:8)
    at exports.info (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/user.js:13:9)
    at callbacks (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at complete (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:218:13)
    at /home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:200:15
    at pass (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:399:14)
    at Passport.transformAuthInfo (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:415:5)
```

Request are send by curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer NoulKM889Aksf60rQONcUJwMuZHI3PDqzeXfkX3Li2BohsxNVsOrd2LLdvJAGZuE168IukUCPbviazhvBjt7VDfLFUMJRIY1fa95kGXQQKzE7etFhocsnYvbLSixbHRmCwXNx5FKj6v83Ci9f9xLqRinEKwaAUIjs03hhq8dCWIp7S0Cbi5jdkxlzwfpZxuShoAZYaFInlf4ymG5oyzQe0WJ2POXOaMarGLO7NkjyIMJXWh7s0Y" http://localhost:3000/api/userinfo
```

I use passport-http-bearer, oAuth2orize, and all example functions presented in OAuth2orize examples.

Could you please explain me why ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you attempted to set a response header after the response was sent back.  Check to make sure you didn't call `res.end()` (or a similar method) before you tried to set the headers.

Comment: I never call res.end() or other call ... I only call passport check with :
`exports.info2 = [
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user)
  }
]`

And bearer strategy not allow my request, but the strategy find user in DB.

Comment: I was just trying to interpret the error message for you.  What's going on at exports.info (/home/lolostates/Developpement/nodejs/oauth2/test/user.js:13:9)?  That appears to be where you try to set the headers after the fact.

Comment: Sorry for my english, i don't have all words.
`var passport = require('passport')

exports.info = [
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json({ user_id: req.user.uid, name: req.user.mail, scope: req.authInfo.scope })
  }
]`


I call only passport and return a json. Passport stop process and send 401 unauthorize even if he find a user in DB.

Comment: It's seems that passport send a bad authenticated response before receve result from mysql. She does not wait MySQL result. What do you think ?

Comment: Perhaps your database query was asynchronous?